# TFS Java SDK throws Out of Memory Exception

Tags: java, tfs, sdk

I am studying on TFS Java SDK, use Java to connect TFS server and do query.
It shows a Out of memory exception.

```
Exception in thread "ReplicaSetStatus:Updater" Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Out of Memory
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.tfs.core.internal.db.ConnectionConfiguration.createNewConnection(ConnectionConfiguration.java:219)
```

Till now i have no idea about this.
Could you kingly help this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try increasing the memory allocated to SQuirreL. Open the script or batch file in a text editor and change the amount of memory allocated. Look for -Xmx256m and replace the 256 with a larger number.

On Windows the file is squirrel-sql.bat, on Linux it is squirrel-sql.sh

Comment: Thanks, it works. But i am still thinking if this is coused by my code.